# Python -- Cant acces class variables in class methods

Tags: python, class, scope, init

Hey I'm trying to make a Player class for my game that uses arrow keys and implements gravity, but i cant use my *init* paramaters in my classes methods to update the position and such, can someone tell me why pleasee? My error is

```
File "playerClass.py", line 83, in <module>
CircleMan.update()
```

File "playerClass.py", line 28, in update
    self.yPos += self.yVel
AttributeError: Player instance has no attribute 'yPos'

```
class Player:
def __init__(self,image,xPos,yPos,xVel,yVel):
    self.xPos = xPos
    self.xPos = yPos
    self.xVel = xVel
    self.yVel = yVel
    self.Image = image

def draw(self):
    screen.blit(Image,(xPos,yPos))

def update(self):
    self.xPos += self.xVel
    self.yPos += self.yVel

    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_LEFT:
                        self.xVel = -2
                    elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                        self.xVel = 2
                    elif event.key == K_UP:
                        if self.yPos == 469:  ## if player presses down up and player is on the ground, subtract y value making him jump
                            self.yVel = -3
                    elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                         pass


            if event.type == KEYUP:
                    if event.key == K_LEFT:
                        self.xVel = 0
                    elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                        self.xVel = 0
                    elif event.key == K_UP:
                        self.yVel = 0
                    elif event.key == K_DOWN:  
                        self.yVel = 0

    playerGravity()
    draw()

def playerGravity(self):
    if self.yPos < 469:
        self.yVel = self.yVel + 2
    elif yPos == 469:
        self.yVel = 0
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably made a typo in the **init**() function. You are setting self.xPos twice, but self.yPos is not set.

def **init**(self,image,xPos,yPos,xVel,yVel):
    self.xPos = xPos
    self.xPos = yPos
    self.xVel = xVel
    self.yVel = yVel
    self.Image = image

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in your constructor:

```
self.xPos = yPos
```

Should be :

```
self.yPos = yPos
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a typo in the question you have defined `self.xPos` twice

```
  self.xPos = xPos
  self.xPos = yPos
```

and never define `self.yPos`

Comment: i have fixed that already, but now my player object is starting with a y value of 77858

Comment: okay, now i have my object updating correctly ( i set the update method to print x and y values) but i cant actually see my player, what have i done wrong?

Comment: okay, i got it i had to pass a screen parameter to my class so it would draw in the same screen as my background :) thanks for the help guys!

Comment: sure, please mark one of the solutions as correct if they are or else you could post your own solution and choose it as correct but I think our answers do solve the original problem.